# Cusps of congruence subgroup

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

Let $\Gamma$ be a congruence subgroup and let $F$ be its fundamental domain.

My first question is: Do the *cusps of* $\Gamma$ can be defined as elements of $\partial F\cap\mathbb{P^1(\mathbb{Q})}$? ($\partial F$ means the boundary of $F$).

My second question is: Does the *fan width*  of $\Gamma_0(N)$ equal $1$.

Comment: The answer to your first question is yes. For your second question, I have never heard the phrase "fan width".

Comment: @PeterHumphries Thank you very much. Indeed the "fan width"  is the minimum $h > 0$ such that $\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & h \\ 0& 1\end{array}\right)\in\Gamma_0(N)$

Comment: Then yes, it is $1$ for $\Gamma_0(N)$. (I don't think this is standard terminology.)

Comment: @PeterHumphries, Thank you very much for your answer.